# Pandas duplicate datetimeindex entries lead to odd exception

Tags: python, pandas

Let's take the following contrived example where I create a `DataFrame` and then make a `DatetimeIndex` using a column with duplicate entries. I then place this `DataFrame` into a `Panel` and then attempt to iterate over the major axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

a = [1371215933513120, 1371215933513121, 1371215933513122, 1371215933513122]
b = [1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':[dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(t/1000000.) for t in a]})
df.index=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['c'])

d = OrderedDict()
d['x'] = df
p = pd.Panel(d)

for y in p.major_axis:
    print y
    print p.major_xs(y)
```

This leads to the following output:

```
2013-06-14 15:18:53.513120
                            x
a            1371215933513120
b                           1
c  2013-06-14 15:18:53.513120
2013-06-14 15:18:53.513121
                            x
a            1371215933513121
b                           2
c  2013-06-14 15:18:53.513121
2013-06-14 15:18:53.513122
```

Followed by a rather cryptic (to me) error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-045aaae5a074> in <module>()
     13 for y in p.major_axis:
     14     print y
---> 15     print p.major_xs(y)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py in __str__(self)
    667         if py3compat.PY3:
    668             return self.__unicode__()
--> 669         return self.__bytes__()
    670 
    671     def __bytes__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py in __bytes__(self)
    677         """
    678         encoding = com.get_option("display.encoding")
--> 679         return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
    680 
    681     def __unicode__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py in __unicode__(self)
    692             # This needs to compute the entire repr
    693             # so don't do it unless rownum is bounded
--> 694             fits_horizontal = self._repr_fits_horizontal_()
    695 
    696         if fits_vertical and fits_horizontal:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py in _repr_fits_horizontal_(self)
    652             d=d.iloc[:min(max_rows, height,len(d))]
    653 
--> 654         d.to_string(buf=buf)
    655         value = buf.getvalue()
    656         repr_width = max([len(l) for l in value.split('\n')])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py in to_string(self, buf, columns, col_space, colSpace, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, nanRep, index_names, justify, force_unicode, line_width)
   1489                                            header=header, index=index,
   1490                                            line_width=line_width)
-> 1491         formatter.to_string()
   1492 
   1493         if buf is None:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/format.py in to_string(self, force_unicode)
    312             text = info_line
    313         else:
--> 314             strcols = self._to_str_columns()
    315             if self.line_width is None:
    316                 text = adjoin(1, *strcols)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/format.py in _to_str_columns(self)
    265         for i, c in enumerate(self.columns):
    266             if self.header:
--> 267                 fmt_values = self._format_col(i)
    268                 cheader = str_columns[i]
    269 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/format.py in _format_col(self, i)
    403                             float_format=self.float_format,
    404                             na_rep=self.na_rep,
--> 405                             space=self.col_space)
    406 
    407     def to_html(self, classes=None):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/format.py in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify)
   1319                         justify=justify)
   1320 
-> 1321     return fmt_obj.get_result()
   1322 
   1323 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/format.py in get_result(self)
   1335 
   1336     def get_result(self):
-> 1337         fmt_values = self._format_strings()
   1338         return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)
   1339 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/format.py in _format_strings(self)
   1362 
   1363         print "vals:", vals
-> 1364         is_float = lib.map_infer(vals, com.is_float) & notnull(vals)
   1365         leading_space = is_float.any()
   1366 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2) (2,3)
```

Now, having explained that I'm creating an index with duplicate entries, the source of the error is clear. Without having known that, however, it would have been more difficult (again, for a novice like me) to figure out why this Exception was popping up.

This leads me to a few questions.

1. Is this really the expected behavior of pandas? Is it forbidden to create an index with duplicate entries, or is it just forbidden to iterate over them?
2. If it's forbidden to create such an index, then shouldn't an exception be raised when initially creating it?
3. If the iteration is somehow incorrect, shouldn't the error be more informative?
4. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: the 2nd part of your post (starts with ``key``), what code generated this?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I had put some debugging statements in the pandas code to try and figure out what was happening in pandas before I realized the problem was due to the duplicate entries. I changed it to contain the stock output.

Comment: ok....dup column support going to be much better in 0.12 (but this still errors). Duplicates are supported in a lot of cases. Generally it is not a good idea to have duplicates in a single-level index; use a MultiIndex see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex. I'll mark this as a bug. Can you show what you goal is here, I can help you make a structure to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks Jess. To be honest, this workflow is actually a bug in my code as well (I should never have duplicate time stamps). The problem is that I didn't know I had duplicates until after I spent a bit of time trying to figure out why this error was appearing.

Comment: np.....I use Panels a lot, but very careful about dups (I generally read/write them to HDF5)